# not sure why the second if else condition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAxEW.jpg)Scenario: Even if i select the image and date the code is not working.
Also if i select year 2020 n say am selecting the first image it should go the specified redirecting page... when i select the year 2021 n the same first image it should go to another page...If i use the else if giving the condition "2020 n img" it is not working.

Code: "For submit Button"

```
<p align=center>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
        </p>





<script type="text/javascript">
let _img = document.getElementById("img");
let _img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
let _img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
let _picker = document.getElementById("picker");
let _btn = document.getElementById("button");

let isImgClicked = false;
let isDatePicked = false;
_img.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
});
_img1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
});
_img2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
});
_picker.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isDatePicked = true;
});
_btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

              if(!isImgClicked || !isDatePicked)
              {
                  alert("select the Year and Click the car image");

              }
              else 
                 {
                  if((isImgClicked == "img") && (isDatePicked == "2020"))
                     {
                        window.location.replace("sample.html");
                     }
                  else if((isImgClicked == "img") && (isDatePicked == "2019"))
                     {
                   window.location.replace("sample1.html");
                     }
                  else
                      {
                        if((isImgClicked == "img1") && (isDatePicked == "2019"))
                  {
                  window.location.replace("sample2.html");
                  }
              else if((isImgClicked == "img1") && (isDatePicked == "2020"))
                  {
                   window.location.replace("sample3.html");
                  }
              else
                  {
                  alert("!!!!")
                  }
                 }
                 }
        });
</script>
```

For images:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <form>
                    <div id="img" class="swiper-slide"
                        style="background-image: url(./img/nature.png)">
                        <b>nature</b>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div id="img1" class="swiper-slide"
                    style="background-image: url(./img/nature1.png)">
                    <b>nature1</b>
                </div>
                <div id="img2 "class="swiper-slide"
                    style="background-image: url(./img/nature2.png)">
                    <b>nature2</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
```

Date Picker:

```
    <div id="picker">
        <p align="center">
            <b>Year:</b> <input type="text" id="datepicker">
        </p>
    </div>
<script>
  $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
            }
        });

       $("#datepicker").focus(function () {
            $(".ui-datepicker-month").hide();
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        });

    });
  </script>[enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: Can you please explain your if else conditions a bit??? I found it confusing... What is the condition for redirection and not redirection??

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane , Yes.. First both the date n image should be clicked.. The second this is..there are three images and year to be selected. if i click on the first image and year as 2020 it should redirect to "index.html-second else if condition" and if the click the same image n diff year it has to go to another page.

Comment: Another means??? Newfile.html???

Comment: No, need to write anothe elseif condition for that selecting img1 n 2019 redirecting to diff page..frst testing with one else if condition which is not working..

Comment: I have edited the condition as per the requirement..depending the selected year even if it is the same image , it should fetch the following year details.

Comment: totally 3 images.. for the first one - "div id="img" ,  second one - div id="img1", Third image - div id="img2"  ....

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, What if imageClicked is img and year is 2019??? What does your console say in any click???

Comment: as per the code , for clicking the first image alone it should go to the Else part..bfr adding else if condition this else part atlst was working..now that is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I have coded pretty much for you. There were lots of errors in there.
First of all, you simply could not check boolean with string like you did or I did.
Boolean only have true or false. This line of code was just so dummy mistake as I explained:

```
isImgClicked.equals("img1")  // This will always be false as isImgClicked is boolean only
```

Now, here is what I have done, keeping that you have already embedded jquery in your page. Feel free to ask, if there is any doubt.

```
        let _img = document.getElementById("img");
        let _img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
        let _img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
        let _btn = document.getElementById("button");

        let isImgClicked = false;
        let isDatePicked = false;

        /* If any event is clicked!!!! */
        $(document).on('click', function(e){
            clickId = e.target.id;           // Get id of clicked element
            pickedDate = $('#datepicker').val();      // Get value of date picked

            // If picked date value is not null, means date is picked
            if(pickedDate.length > 0){
                isDatePicked = true;
            }
            if(clickId == 'img' || clickId == 'img1' || clickId == 'img2'){
                isImgClicked = true;
                selectedImg = clickId;  // Get id of selected image
            }
            if(clickId == 'button')
            {
                if(!isImgClicked)
                {
                    alert("select the Year and Click the car image");
                }
                else 
                {
                    if((selectedImg == "img") && (pickedDate == "2020"))
                        window.location.replace("sample.html");
                    else if((selectedImg == "img") && (pickedDate == "2019"))
                        window.location.replace("sample1.html");
                    else if((selectedImg == "img1") && (pickedDate == "2019"))
                        window.location.replace("sample2.html");
                    else if((selectedImg == "img1") && (pickedDate == "2020"))
                        window.location.replace("sample3.html");
                    else
                        alert("!!!!")
                }
            }
        });
```

You should be able to fix any other problem by now. There may be div id's mix match to look upto. You could replace your js code for submit button with this one and check for the errors. Thank you!!!

Comment: yes i feel the same, am not sure what is wrong since am a beginner. have edited now with foll conditions in the above code

Comment: yes its correct but after submit its still on the same page..am getting the below error as in the url , "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAxEW.jpg"

Comment: Can you put semicolon at the end of each click function and let me know??

Comment: Yes after adding semicolon also, it is throwing the same error.

Comment: Can you send the error pic??? Not zoomed one, we need to see what type of error is it..

Comment: Can you replace the ()=>{ } with function(){ } and let me know. There should not be problem.. but still.... Also, it would be helpful if you show the image of "Enter bookmark" also

Comment: yes now the error has gone.. but after clicking on submitting it is not redirecting

Comment: Can you change __window.location__ with __window.location.replace("index.html");__ like this?? And let me know..

Comment: Getting excuted but not the logic... If i click submit without clicking either date n img ... "Image Not clicked" and "!!!!" is displaying .... BUt i click the condition is not getting executed..I have edited the following code in the qstn (For button)

Comment: i have edited the above code , the issue is boolean cant accept string thats why esle part is not getting executed. But am not sure how to proceed further

Comment: Oh!!!!!! There are so dummy mistakes.. Okay, let me change that!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jquery and jqueryui libraries? If not, copy the following lines at the beginning, e.g. head section, of your code:

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Moreover, correct this line:

```
<div id="img2 "class="swiper-slide"
```

with this line:

```
<div id="img2"class="swiper-slide"
```

Comment: I added the below lines:

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: i have corrected the div tag, for only the first image it working. for second and third it not getting redirected

Comment: Ok, I look if I find another potential bug

Comment: sure, it would be great help

Comment: In case have a look on the console of the inspector if it displays errors